# parent.opener doesn't work in webview Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, parent

I have a problem. I need to return to parent `Url` from Frame opened in a Android `Webview`.

The sequence is: Open inside `Webview` new frame. Select in frame options and paramters. Call in frame `javascript` function like _"javascript:parent.opener.*jsfunction*"_. Parent Web doesn't open...
I don't have access to Web. I work only in Android side.

I test Web in a firefox for Android and it works.

Need help.

Comment: Do you have the proper permissions set up in your Android Manifest? Internet permission, etc.

Comment: Yes, I work with Webviews frequently, manifests permissions are correct, I can navigate for other Webs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `WebView` doesn't support multiple windows. If you check, I believe the `parent` field actually isn't set and doesn't point to the parent window (or anything at all). The same applies to other similar fields like `opener` and `top`.

You might be able to work through this by [enabling support for multiple windows](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSupportMultipleWindows%28boolean%29) and then implementing [`onCreateWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onCreateWindow%28android.webkit.WebView,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20android.os.Message%29) in your `WebChromeClient`. I think there's some more you have to do, but it's been a while and I don't recall the details.

One way I've hacked around this in the past is to use [setJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) and just set the name to `parent` or whichever field you want. Implement the appropriate methods as necessary on your Java object. This can get a bit messy, but it works.

Comment: Thanks, Finally I found the solution enabling support for multiple windows and then implementing onCreateWindow in your WebChromeClient. Aftre a lot of test work it!

Comment: Would you please share what you did in the onCreateWindow(), I have a problem uploading an image via webView and I got this error, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", source: "